# Problem with values on disk

Tags: calculus

Hello I am having trouble figuring out how to do this problem. and the solution is not in the back so I am not able to check this.

I am trying to finding the maximum values of $$ f(x,y)=5x^2-22xy+5y^2+8$$ in the disk $x^2+y^2 \le 25$.

Now, I have a done problems similar, but there issue here is the term that contains both the xy; il explain,

what I have done:

$$f_x =10x-22y$$
$$f_y=-22x+10y$$

and setting equal to zero to find critical points

has only the solution $x=y=0$

Noting, $f(0,0)=8$

So now I want to check the boundaries, which I know can usually be done by bringing in a new function

$x^2+y^2=25 \rightarrow x^2=25-y^2$

But because of the $-22xy$ I wont be able to get rid of one variable efficiently, will I? Any hints for this?

Comment: The $5x^2+5y^2$ clearly maximizes on the edge of the disk. The $-22xy$ produces a gradient across the disk - find the maximum (maxima) of that on the edge of the disk and you're done. By symmetry, it's not that hard.

Comment: Also, the question is not allowed to be solved using gradient/langrange

Comment: OK, but it will give you a reference to check your answer against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are maximizing $5x^2+5y^2-22xy+8$ on the circle.  So we want to minimize $22xy$ on the circle. There are many ways, for example think polar. We want to minimize $(22)(5\cos\theta)(5\sin\theta)$. Note that the minimum value of $2\sin\theta\cos\theta$ is $-1$.

Comment: Thanks, im sorry I should have mentioned in post. No polar allowed either. Only strictly partial derivatives in regular coordinates, is it possible?

Comment: One can use one-variable calculus reasoning.  We maximize $x^2y^2$ and pick the negative value of $xy$ that does the job. Since $x^2+y^2=25$, we are maximizing $x^2(25-x^2)$. Simple one variable calculus, if we want to use derivatives. If we don't need to use derivatives, complete the square.

Comment: Hm, how should I go about it if I complete the square? just factor?

Comment: We are maximizing $x^2(25-x^2)$, which is $\frac{25^2}{4}-\left(\frac{25}{2}-x^2\right)^2$. The max is when $x^2=\frac{25}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks, but how can we know that maxamizing that is equivalent to maximizing the whole expression?

Comment: The $5x^2+5y^2$ part is fixed. As explained in the answer, we want to **minimize** $22xy$. By symmetry, we can equivalently maximize $x^2y^2$, and choose $xy$ negative.

Comment: Thank you, I will also try the polar approach to see, I eventually get to $-275sin(2 \theta)$ which now I solve for when it is 1 and -1 and plug back in?

Comment: max is $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and min is $\theta=\frac{3\pi}{4}$  Is what I solve it for, now when i plug back into x, do i maintain the new coordinates?

Comment: Sorry for keeping to ask I just  really want to understand, but I think. Would you mind just telling me if you think my value are correct? max is 408 and min is -142? Thank you a lot sir

Comment: Sorry about lateness in replying, I was away. The max is $133+(11)(25)$, the min is $133-(11)(25). These are the numbers you got.

Answer (score 0):

The "critical point" analysis you give is correct, but not complete.  If we check the "concavity index" for the surface, we obtain

$$ D \ = \ f_{xx} \ f_{yy} \ - \ ( f_{xy})^2 \ = \ 10 \ \cdot \ 10 \ - \ (-22)^2 \ < \ 0 \ \ , $$

telling us that the sole critical point at the origin is a "saddle point".  So there are no extrema within the constraint disk.  (For some reason, a lot of problems on this site are turning up with circles of radius 5 centered on the origin.)

I am assuming from your post that you may be unfamiliar with the Lagrange-multiplier method, or were not allowed to use it (so I'll save that for the end).  You also say you were not permitted polar coordinates.

Here is a way in which we can exploit the symmetry of the functions.  Since both the function to be extremized *and* the constraint function are symmetric about the origin, the extremal points will share this symmetry.  So they will lie diametrically opposite one another on the constraint circle on lines through the origin $ \ y \ = \ kx \ $ .

The $ \ x-$ coordinates of the extremal points on the constraint circle are then given by

$$ x^2 \ + \ (kx)^2 \ = \ 25 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x^2 \ = \ \frac{25}{1 + k^2} \ \ . $$

On the constraint circle, our function becomes

$$ f( k) \ = \ ( \ 5 \ - \ 22k \ + \ 5 \ k^2 \ ) \ x^2 \ + \ 8 \ = \ \frac{25 \ ( \ 5 \ - \ 22k \ + \ 5 \ k^2 \ )}{1 + k^2} \ + \ 8 \ \ . $$

The "critical directions" for the extremal points are found from

$$ \frac{df}{dk} \ = \ \frac{25 \cdot 22 \ (  k^2 \ - \ 1 )}{[ \ 1 + k^2 \ ]^2} \ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ k \ = \ \pm 1 \ \ . $$

Hence, the extremal points are the intersections of the lines $ \ y \ = \ \pm x \ $ with the constraint circle, with $ \ x^2 \ = \ \frac{25}{2} \ $ .  The extrema of our function are thus

$$ f( 1) \ =  \ \frac{25 \ ( \ 5 \ - \ 22 \ + \ 5  \ )}{ 2} \ + \ 8 \ = \ 25 \ (-6) \ + \ 8 \ = \ -142  $$

and

$$ f( -1) \ =  \ \frac{25 \ ( \ 5 \ + \ 22 \ + \ 5  \ )}{ 2} \ + \ 8 \ = \ 25 \ (16) \ + \ 8 \ = \ +408 \ \ .  $$

$ \ \ $

Just to show what the Lagrange-multiplier method produces, the "Lagrange equations" are

$$ 10 \ x \ - \ 22 \ y \ = \ \lambda \ \cdot \ 2 \ x \ \ , \ \ -22 \ x \ + \ 10 \ y \ = \ \lambda \ \cdot \ 2 \ y \ \ . $$

We can re-arrange this into the system of linear equations

$$ \begin{array}{ccc}(10 - 2 \lambda) \ x &- \ 22 \ y& \ = \ 0\\-22 \ x&+ \ (10 - 2 \lambda) \ y&= \ 0\end{array} \ \ , $$

which we know has non-trivial solutions when the coefficient matrix is singular. [In any event, we know that there is no extremum at $ \ (0, \ 0) \ $.]  The determinant is zero for

$$ (10 - 2 \lambda)^2 \ - \ 22^2 \ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \lambda \ = \ \frac{10 \ \mp \ 22}{2} \ = \ -6 \ , \ 16 \ \ . $$

For $ \ \lambda \ = \ -6 \ $ , we obtain $ \ y \ = \ x \ $ , and $ \ \lambda \ = \ 16 \ $ produces $ \ y \ = \ -x \ $ .  Inserting these into the constraint equation and the function $ \ 5x^2 \ - \ 22xy \ + \ 5y^2 \ + \ 8 \ $ reproduces the results discussed above and in **André Nicolas'** answer and subsequent comments.

The level curves for $ \ f(x, \ y) \ $ are "rotated" hyperbolas; we note the geometrical arrangement in the graph below.

[image]